# How to load Java classes for HSQLDB stored procedures in JBoss AS or Glassfish servers

Tags: jboss, glassfish, hsqldb

Is possible to use java stored procedures for HSQLDB in JBoss or Glassfish? If it is possible, Where can the compiled class files for the stored procedures be placed?  Could it placed in the entity bean class?  Any answers are much appreciated.  Thank you,

Comment: [Why “is it possible?” is a poor question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Comment: I hope to migrate java stored procedures in hsqldb, currently in RMI-based,  to JBoss AS platform.

Comment: It is my honor to see my question fixed by my teacher.  Hat off!!